# Type hint function accepting union types

Tags: python, python-typing, union-types, pyright

The following function with argument of type `type` accepts both
regular types and union types and works as expected.
However Pylance treats passing union type as error.

```py
def foo(t: type):
    print(t)

foo(int)
# OK

foo(int | str)
# Pylance:
# Argument of type "type[int] | type[str]"
# cannot be assigned to parameter "t" of type "type"
# in function "foo"
```

What is the correct type hint for any type including union types?

**UPDATE**:

Seems to be [Pyright issue #7110](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/7110) fixed in recent version.

Comment: What is that function supposed to do?

Comment: @InSync This is a purified example. The original function uses `isinstance(..., t)` to find data in a collection. Note that `isinstance` check works fine with union types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the type definition of `isinstance()` from `typeshed` ([permalink](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/9916efae631f9872e78e509d69cc758f627f86c9/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L1385-L1390)):

```py
if sys.version_info >= (3, 10):
    _ClassInfo: TypeAlias = type | types.UnionType | tuple[_ClassInfo, ...]
else:
    _ClassInfo: TypeAlias = type | tuple[_ClassInfo, ...]

def isinstance(__obj: object, __class_or_tuple: _ClassInfo) -> bool: ...
```

`_ClassInfo` is what you need.

On the other hand, if you can modify the function in question, maybe you should apply composition and let it accept a predicate instead:

```py
def foo(predicate: Callable[[Any], bool]) -> None:
  ...
```

Comment: Strangely, `UnionType` doesn't work. I get error even for code like `t: UnionType = int | str`

Comment: @MaksimZholudev I can't reproduce the problem (playground links: [mypy](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=5a0b753b93b5762b67dec0c6a3dbe361), [Pyright](https://pyright-play.net/?pythonVersion=3.12&strict=true&code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwKYGcoEsILCGUCqAdumIQCqJICwAULQPoDCANgIYooCShwYUAvAWKkKyKAB9YlCbACuCZkgDaAciZsO3XioA0UAHSGAurVoATJMCi8wAChgAuKOvZceYAJRQAtAD4oAHKkSA60UOFQCCDohDD2HqY0NrYxMF4RGQDE1jHUSWB2qTIoMCDp2cC5tEA)). Please edit your question to include a [mre].