# How to type annotate a Python function that should work similar to typeguard.check_type?

Tags: python-3.x, mypy, pyright

I want implement a Python function that works like typeguard.check_type, but does additional reporting (particular to my project's needs) in case of failure.

What is the correct type annotation for a function like that?

Ideally it should at-least work with Pyright and Mypy.

I have tried the following solution:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar, Any
from typeguard import check_type

T = TypeVar('T')

def my_check_type(s: Any, t: Type[T]) -> T:
    return check_type(s, t)

x = my_check_type(10, float | int)
```

It works for simple types with pyright, but not when the passed type is a union type.
Pyright complains:

```
Argument of type "type[float] | type[int]" cannot be assigned to parameter
"t" of type "type[T@my_check_type]" in function "my_check_type"
(Pyright reportArgumentType)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Type hint function accepting union types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78059868/type-hint-function-accepting-union-types)

Comment: No it doesn't. I can add an overload with (t: UnionType) but then the typechecker can't infer the return type.